TypeScript 'Mapped Types' with capitalization
Is there any difference between these 2 mapped types?
type UppercaseProperties1<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as Capitalize<string & P>]: T[P]
}

type UppercaseProperties2<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as Capitalize<P & string>]: T[P]
}

I see that in the TypeScript playground a simple type like Person
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

gives the same result for each of these mapped types:
type UppercasePerson = {
    Name: string;
    Age: number;
}

But perhaps there are some cases where this nuance can make a difference?

Try on a type that has symbol or number properties. For string-keyed properties, it should not make a difference indeed

@Bergi I tried 123: boolean property and symbol as well, but the result is still the same  - non-string properties are ignored in both cases.

I'm pretty sure this violates the generative AI policy; please [edit] your question to remove the chatbot's response to your question. It's good that you mentioned that you asked AI, though, because that answer is completely bonkers and incorrect. There's not going to be any meaningful difference between string & P and P & string. Intersections are largely order-independent, especially if you're not overloading functions, which you're not. There's just no difference between string & P and P & string when P is some key type.

@jcalz ok, thanks!

There's no difference.  The intersections string & P and P & string are the same. In most cases intersection order doesn't matter at all. There are some situations where it does matter, such as when intersecting functions in which case TypeScript treats them as overloads which are order-dependent. But in the example code where P is a keylike type parameter from a mapped type, then P & string and string & P is either going to be just P (if P extends string is true) or never (if P extends string is false).  So there's no difference at all.
